# How can stdin / stdout of unrelated & previously running processes be accessed?

Tags: c, pipe, stdout, stdin, io-redirection

Given two programs Program1.c and Program2.c, which are both executed separately as their own unrelated programs/processes:

Program1 knows the PID of Program2, and vise versa.

What C code (not shell commands) must both programs use to link their stdin/stdout to the other's stdout/stdin?

Comment: Why not just use a socket?

Comment: Or a fifo/named pipe?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9689498/feedback-stdin-and-stdout-of-two-processes

Comment: Which o/s are you using?  They'd each have to close their existing standard input and output and open mutually agreed connections — possibly Unix-domain sockets.

Comment: I don't know much about sockets, but know a pipe is more efficient/speedy for local inter-process communications, based on a quick google.     As for namedpipes, i believe thats what stdon/stdout already is, and id rather use whats already there than coordinate new onesfor each separate program.       Related question doesn't appear to be C, I want to link them within the sourcecode, not from a shell.  As for OS, the target is linux, but im coding on windows and osx, so, the most universal option OR the answer for each os.  Sometimes itll be implimented on arduino n stufflike that

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (at least as far as I know). The memory for `stdin` and `stdout` is deallocated as soon as the program ends.

Comment: You're confusing `/proc/self/fd/` with `/dev/pts/`, and snooping the latter won't let the processes communicate, merely access the same data.

Comment: @o11c The question said "previously running processes". Should I just keep "it's not possible ..."?

Comment: It's certainly possible with a socket, named pipe, or even an anonymous pipe + snooping /proc/<otherpid>/fd/, but OP hasn't answered the followup questions.